# Migrate comma separated string to json array

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, data-migration, mysql-5.7

I have an old database, where some columns have comma separated strings stored like this `technician,director,website designer`

I want to convert them to a JSON array, so I can use the MySQL JSON array type and the methods associated with it.
So basically I am looking for a method to convert `technician,director,website designer` to `["technician","director","website designer"]` in SQL.

The length of the list is arbitrary.
The biggest struggle I am having is how to apply a SQL function on each element in the comma separated string, (So I for example can run the `JSON_QUOTE()` on each element) as adding the brackets are just a simple `CONCAT`.

The solution should be for MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` to get the expected string:

```
SELECT CONCAT('["', REPLACE('technician,director,website designer', ',', '","'), '"]')
-- ["technician","director","website designer"]
```

Using [`JSON_VALID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid) you can check if the result of the conversion is a valid JSON value:

```
SELECT JSON_VALID(CONCAT('["', REPLACE('technician,director,website designer', ',', '","'), '"]'))
-- 1
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=28ea6364b2e0fae1c244662d2a1212a4)

Comment: Nice! Simple solution, did not think of that.
I had one entry which was invalid, because it had a ", but, I just added a replace to escape it.